# why strlen () replace a string?

Tags: c, string, function, strlen

I got a pgm from internet. But I am confused about a code about strlen () function . Is it strlen() replace a string ? I am beginner in this coding .help me .

### simple code block below :

```
while(NULL != fgets(Buffer, 4095, Input))
{
    char *Stop = NULL;
    char *Start = Buffer;

    while(1)
    {

        Stop = strstr(Start, Find);
        if(NULL == Stop)
        {
            fwrite(Start, 1, strlen(Start), Output);
            break;
        }
        printf("\n@found at Line  <%d>",line);
        fwrite(Start, 1, Stop - Start, Output);
        fwrite(Replace, 1, strlen(Replace), Output);
        Start = Stop + strlen(Find);
    }
    line++;
}
```

why  `start = stop + strlen(find)` replace a string ?

Comment: Do you understand what is pointer ?

Comment: Do you already know what pointer arithmetic is?

Comment: strlen() returns the length of a string

Answer (score 3):

> Is it strlen() replace a string ?

No, computes the length of the string passed to it.

> why  `start = stop + strlen(find)` replace a string ?

`=` is called assignment operator, which assigns value of right operand to left operand. `a = b;` Means value of `b` is assigned to `a`. Hope it make sense.

I would suggest pick a text book, first go through basic concepts operators, string, functions and pointers. Then you will understand what exactly your code is doing.